# Replace React component onClick

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that has a button container on the main screen that I can't figure out how to do the conditional rendering for.

**APP.js**

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showComponent: false,
    };
  }

... 
 render() {
    return (
{
  !this.state.showComponent ? (
    <div className="button_wrapper">
      <>
        <button
          className="upload_button"
          onClick={this.setState({ showComponent: true })}
        >
          {" "}
          {i18next.t("GENERAL.uploadBill")}
        </button>

        <p className="or_txt"> {i18next.t("GENERAL.or")}</p>
        <button className="manual_button">
          {" "}
          {i18next.t("GENERAL.fillManually")}
        </button>
      </>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <>
      <ComponentToShow />
    </>
  );
}
```

The idea is that the state `showComponent` is initially set to `false` and onclick of the button inside of the conditional statement, the container with the current buttons should be replaced with the new component. However, I'm not sure that this conditional should be wrapping the button with this onClick event. Is there a more efficient way to do this without having to create a separate component for the button area?

Comment: `onClick={() => this.setState({ showComponent: true })}`. The on click event handler takes a function, not a function call.